# Tkinter OptionMenu delete

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to completely delete OptionMenu from your grid widget? Without any side module.

I've tried some approaches, nothing worked:

```
# forget from grid
option_menu.grid_forget()

# reset to default
option_menu = OptionMenu(master, None, None)

# delete items
option_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: `option_menu.grid_forget()` or `option_menu.destroy()` should be able to remove the widget from the container.  Is there any error when using `option_menu.grid_forget()`?  Or do you want to clear all the items in `option_menu` instead?

Comment: ***"# reset to default"***: This will reset nothing, you creat a new widget instaed. Read up on [Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the widget from view you have two choices:

The first choice is to call the "forget" method for whichever geometry manager you're using (either `grid_forget()`,  `pack_forget()`, or `place_forget()`). This will cause the widget to be removed from the window, but the widget will still exist. You can make it reappear by calling `grid`, `pack`, or `place`.

If you want to completely throw away the widget, you can call the `destroy` method: `option_menu.destroy()`. This will both remove it from view and also destroy the underlying widget.

Comment: `destroy()` was what I exactly want.